# AFNetworking and POST Request

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I'm getting this response in error.userInfo while making a POST request from `AFNetworking`.
Can anyone tell either I'm missing anything obvious or something need to fix at my server end?

> Request Failed with Error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain
>   Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
>       "text/json",
>       "application/json",
>       "text/javascript" )}, got text/html" UserInfo=0x6d7a730 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=index test,
>   AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://54.245.14.201/,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
>       "text/json",
>       "application/json",
>       "text/javascript" )}, got text/html, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=http://54.245.14.201/>}, {
>       AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey = "http://54.245.14.201/>";
>       AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey = "";
>       NSErrorFailingURLKey = "http://54.245.14.201/";
>       NSLocalizedDescription = "Expected content type {(\n    \"text/json\",\n    \"application/json\",\n
>   \"text/javascript\"\n)}, got text/html";
>       NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = "index test"; }

And I'm using this code;

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
[httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"Ans", @"name",
                        @"29", @"age",
                        nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/" parameters:params];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
        NSLog(@"%@",JSON);

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
        NSLog(@"Failure");
}];

[operation start];
[operation waitUntilFinished];
```

Comment: an ask, why do you have "[operation waitUntilFinished];"? Is this needed and is it a blocking call? Thanks! :)

Comment: so... where/how in the above code did you implement the accepted solution?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

By default, `AFJSONRequestOperation` accepts only "text/json", "application/json" or "text/javascript" content-types from server, but you are getting "text/html".

Fixing on server would be better, but you can also add "text/html" content type as acceptable in your app:

```
[AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];
```

It worked for me, hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Did you send this POST request by `AFHTTPClient`? If so, you need to set operation class for it:

```
AFHTTPClient * client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080"]];
// ...
[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
// ...

// EDIT: Use AFHTTPClient's POST method
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         @"Ans", @"name",
                         @"29",  @"age", nil];

// POST, and for GET request, you need to use |-getPath:parameters:success:failure:|
[client postPath:@"/"
      parameters:params
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
           NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@", responseObject);
           // ...
         }
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
           if (error)
             NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
           // ...
         }
```

Comment: Yes; I'm using AFHTTPClient, and have set mentioned class as well; Please look into my code, I just edited my question;

Comment: @Ans there's a `-postPath:parameters:success:` method for AFHTTPClient. Have you tried it?

Comment: Thanks for your response; I tried your code but now neither the success nor the failure block was executed;

Comment: Ya I did; (: I just copied how you send the request using [client postPath:parameters: etc ...

Comment: @Ans that's weird..I do POST request successfully in this way. I think there might be a issue exists somewhere else (on your sever, or ..). :S

Comment: @Ans please do some logging like my code of new edit version.

Answer (score 0):

Set your values in this code and check if it works for you

```
 AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kBASEURL]];
        NSString *_path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"groups/"];
        _path = [_path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%s %@",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,_path);
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" 
                                                                path:_path
                                                          parameters:postParams];
        [httpClient release];

        AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation 
                                             JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                             success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
                                                 if ([JSON isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] || [JSON isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                                                     completed(JSON);
                                                 }
                                                 else {
                                                 }
                                                 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];                                             

                                             } 
                                             failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                                 NSLog(@" response %@  \n error %@ \n JSON %@",response,error,JSON);
                                                 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];                                         
                                                 errored(error);
                                             }];

        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
        [queue addOperation:operation];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
```

Comment: here kBASEURL would like http://xyz.com/api and groups/ is an api end point right?? umm .. well I  tried this but when it sent the call, nothing happen then; Not sure what actually happening; Even if my url isn't in right form, altest throw an erro etc in failure block etc;

Comment: I put my base url in place of kBASEURL and put replace your groups/ with my api end point; Is that ok?

Comment: yea.. its ok dude, One more thing; leave these things first try a simple thing... if you have google chrome install XHRPoster and fill/place the necessary data there and hit the api... and verify the stuff... if is accepted there then it shouldnt be a problem here but if its not then it certainly is a problem at ur server end.

Comment: I have to ship one of my project form ASIHttp to AFNetworking but got stuck in post request; It working well in one of my GET call;

Comment: Try it with Google XHRPoster and verify the response against the necessary data required by api... if it works there it must work here... you can get the XHR POSTER FROM HERE https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/akdbimilobjkfhgamdhneckaifceicen

Comment: Yes its working fine with REST client in firefox; Returned me proper json response;