# Requesting data from Codeigniter to AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, codeigniter, afnetworking, nsurlrequest

I built a simple website with Codeigniter framework (www.imlecturer.arkmon.co.uk). It displays list of people according to search form. My json search request is `index.php/find/findemp`. Search fields names are `firstname` and `dept`. Now I want to send search request from iPhone with AFNetworking and display the same list as a table view from which I will send request for more details (url:`/index.php/find/display/23`). 
I have this code in iPhone:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.imlecturer.arkmon.co.uk/index.php/find/findemp"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation;
operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *req, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id jsonObject) {


...cell.textLabel.text = [tweet objectForKey:@"firstName"];
```

This shows error and displays whole database

```
Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
"text/json",
"application/json",
"text/javascript"
)}, got text/html"
```

Comment: I believe you're looking for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12726827/902968)

Comment: I have seen this before, I actually expect json. My question is how would i change my url. Like: "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=Apple"

Comment: I probably need to setup JSON file but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Use a JSON PHP Content-Type header? `<? header('Content-type: application/json'); ?>` That's wat the error is mentioning..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the solution was to either change the receiver in app as Keith Smiley suggested or creating own JSON generator following [this](http://browse-tutorials.com/tutorial/converting-codeigniter-query-json) and [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/) tutorial.