# Using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking for api of my application

How to write the same request on AFNetworking

```
curl --data "login=test&pass=123456&email=test@test.com" http://somehost.com/api/register.php -X POST
```

Comment: for example check related question before create new one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12447725/1403732 http://stackoverflow.com/q/7623275/1403732

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFNetworking has fantastic documentation. I suggest you check it out.

Here's the link to the current docs to answer your question: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.2.1/Classes/AFHTTPSessionManager.html#//api/name/POST:parameters:success:failure:

The method in AFNetworking 2.2.1's AFHTTPSessionManager is `- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)POST:(NSString *)URLString parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters success:(void ( ^ ) ( NSURLSessionDataTask *task , id responseObject ))success failure:(void ( ^ ) ( NSURLSessionDataTask *task , NSError *error ))failure`. Simply set URLString to your endpoint, implement your query string parameters as the parameters NSDictionary, and setup your success or error blocks as necessary.