# AFNetworking 2 - No response body when request fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, express, afnetworking-2

I am using AFNetworking 2 for an iOS project consuming a REST API. When requests fail, I am not able to get the body response.

I have seen this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19102233/871102) that says it can be retrieved from the `userInfo` dictionary. Unfortunately in my case I am not getting the `NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion` key-value in my `userInfo` dictionary with the response body. Instead I see a `AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey` key.

My `NSError` log is

```
Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo=0xbe471a0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://***.com/api/users, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xbc60e80> { URL: http://***.com/api/users } { status code: 400, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 85;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Thu, 24 Apr 2014 21:36:57 GMT";
    "X-Powered-By" = Express;
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400)}
```

As you can see from the headers, I am getting `"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";` so this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12726827/871102) doesn't apply either.

Actually the body response in [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/) looks like this:

`{"errorCode":100,"description":"There is already a registered user with that email."}`

The backend is implemented by myself in Node + Express. I am not very experienced in backend development though, so maybe there is something I am missing or that I could change.

Does anyone know why I am not getting the response body in `userInfo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Quoting](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/1390#issuecomment-26110839) AFNetworking owner:

> (...) the recommended approach is to create a custom response serializer that translates response data in failing cases into NSError objects as appropriate.

You can see [this answer](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1397#issuecomment-26139898) on another AFNetworking issue to see how to integrate it with your session manager, and [this repository](https://github.com/Hackmodford/HMFJSONResponseSerializerWithData) to see how to implement it.