# AFNetworking not setting correct content type for photo upload

Tags: afnetworking, content-type

So this problem doesn't make sense to me at all because this code worked flawlessly a few months back when i wrote it.  I even made a commit with the message "Photo upload works".  Still, I opened it up last night and couldn't get it to work for the life of me.

The error that I keep getting is          "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"

This makes no sense as I am setting the content-type to image/jpeg!!!!  If anyone has any helpful hints to why this would just stop working i would GREATLY appreciate :) :) :).  The code is below.

```
- (void)postPhoto:(NSData *)ImageToPost forImageUUID:(NSString *)photoUUID {

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://MyURL"]];
[manager setRequestSerializer:[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]];
[manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"michael" password:@"asdf"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"image/jpeg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"name" : @"MyName", @"photo_uid" : photoUUID};

AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:@"/api/photo/" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Photo_%@.jpg",photoUUID];

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:ImageToPost name:@"image" fileName:fileName mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];


} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
}];
[op setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

    NSLog(@"%f%% Uploaded", round(((float)totalBytesWritten / (float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite) * 100));

}];
[op start];
```

}
```

In the end, the photo gets uploaded 100% but then that error kicks off saying its the wrong content-type and the photo never actually gets posted to my server.

Please help :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [AFNetworking and POST Request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447725/afnetworking-and-post-request)

Answer (score 0):

What changed was that the server changed its response format for that endpoint. The error message is that the response from the server is HTML, not JSON as expected by the response serializer.